# Supporting tools for writing chemical/maths equation in android platform

Tags: android, eclipse

We are developing an android app for chemistry. We are using Eclipse for this.

For this application, we need to write so many equations which contain subscript and superscript support to show text for the chemical formula.

For example: H2O, ZnCl2 should be written in proper subscript format. How to solve this?

Please reply.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SpannableStringBuilder` like this..:-

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);//Your texView

        SpannableStringBuilder cs = new SpannableStringBuilder("H2O, ZnCl2");//Your suppose String
        cs.setSpan(new SubscriptSpan(), 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);//Setting span index 
        cs.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan((float)0.75), 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        cs.setSpan(new SubscriptSpan(), 9, 10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        cs.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan((float)0.75), 9, 10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        tv.setText(cs);
```

If you want superscript text, then simply replace `SubscriptSpan` with `SuperscriptSpan` like this.

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);

        SpannableStringBuilder cs = new SpannableStringBuilder("H2O, ZnCl2");
        cs.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        cs.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan((float)0.75), 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        cs.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 9, 10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        cs.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan((float)0.75), 9, 10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        tv.setText(cs);
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a custom font (e.g. DejaVuSans.ttf) for this sort of thing.  Copy the ttf file into assets/fonts and then use it like this :

```
           TextView ttt = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text);

           Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf");
           ttt.setTypeface(font);
           ttt.setText(textString);
```

You then embed unicode characters in the textString : e.g.

f(x)=x\u00B2+2x+3  or you can use a translation table if you prefer to use more meaningful symbols in your formulae.

Comment: How to add this javascript file in my project in Eclipse?

Comment: Javascript ? f(x) is mathematical notation for a function of x . I just used a mathematical function as an example. This is not Javascript.